# processXmlResource cannot reach the xml file

Tags: haxe, haxeui

I'm trying to replicate this [hello world example](http://haxeui.org/wiki/en/XML_Based_UIs) with Haxe and HaxeUI.
When i compile the project everything seems fine but when i try to execute the swf from browser i have an error like: `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference` referred to `processXmlResource` (in the root folder i have the main.hx and in a subfolder the xml).

Below is the screenshot of the error i get: [image]

Comment: Could you maybe paste you application.xml in the original question also? Might help track down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you modified your applications `application.xml` (or `project.xml`) to find the asset in your project root? Or put all your assets in an `assets` sub folder and let then reference that from you `application.xml`?

Basically it seems it is not finding your xml resource. This sample might be a good example of a basic project setup: https://github.com/ianharrigan/haxeui/tree/master/samples/hello_world_xml

Comment: could be related to how i build the project? right now i'm using Intellij and my .hxml file says: `-swf-header 300:200:40:FFFFFF -swf-version 11 -xml a -debug -lib haxeui -lib lime -lib nme -lib openfl`. I'll try with your example and i'll let you know

Comment: ok i executed your code and openfl created a bin folder inside my project, now what should i do with this bin folder? compile it with haxe?

Comment: Whats in the bin folder? That should be the output. what happens if you just run `haxelib run openfl build application.xml flash`?

Comment: Ok now is working the problem whas that i was still compiling with haxe instead of openfl, thanks mate :)